# Can I lazy-load my libraries so they don't delay my app startup?

Tags: iphone, performance, startup

My app takes a long period of time during the startup, while the splash screen is shown. I assume that It is so due to the size of what the iOS has to load, including libraries. My question is, can I load those in the moment the user actually wants to use it, so it makes the startup time shorter?
Are there other ways to do it shorter?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3rd party libraries are statically linked to your app. In theory you can lazy load only Apple's own weakly bound libraries. I am not aware how you can control this process on iOS. It's certainly possible on Mac.

Comment: You can set you linked libraries as weak even if they are 3rd party, (Target>Info>General) but I don't know if this would have any effect.

Comment: @toupper as I understand. The only reason to set linkage is weak is to make sure that your app resolves symbols of the platform your app is in, rather than using symbols of the platform your app was compiled to. It doesn't make any sense to have your own library weak.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can as long as you don't need them directly.

LazyLoad is not limited to what you apply it too, for example if you have a huge Opengl scene you can chose not to laod its textures until the user actually click on the button you need.

The downside of this is that the waiting time to open whatever requires a lazyload will be moved further down the app (when the user wanted to play he will have a longer loading time).

What you could try is to launch Thread that handles the loading at startup and from the thread you do a setBooleanLibXFinishedLoading this way your app will only have to wait for all the booelan to be set to proceed.
This should reduce the apparent waiting time for the user while optimizing the time actually spend loading.

hope this helps

Jason

Comment: Thanks for your response Jason. From your comment this question comes to me: How can I avoid the iOS loading the libreries at the beginning? How can I load them later? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok could you add an example of what you call loading library? (sorry I'm mainly working android at the moment so I a bit rusty on IOS)

Comment: My assumption is that the iOS loads frameworks and libraries we have added to the project (e.g. libGoogleAnalytics.a) at the startup. I don't do anything in the code for loading them, only import the file. Maybe someone more experimented could correct me at this respect.